# Black Screen while running exe file converted from py file with tkinter by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am creating a standalone executable GUI app using Python tkinter and pyinstaller. However, the exe file only shows the console and black screen (refer to the attached img). I have searched for answer for a week including checking other stack overflow posts, but no result. Hope you can help me, many thanks!

[black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nk4t.png)

Here is the code:-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import requests


HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

def test_function(entry):
    print("This is the entry: ", entry)

def format_response(weather):
    try:
        name = weather["name"]
        desc = weather["weather"][0]["description"]
        temp = weather["main"]["temp"]

        final_str = "City: %s \nConditions: %s \nTemperature: %s" %(name, desc, temp)
    except:
        final_str = "There was a problem retrieving that information"

    return final_str

def get_weather(city):
    weather_key = "5164b0c1b7f4019423208f1e0af93cbf"
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    params = {"APPID": weather_key, "q":city, "units":"metric"}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    weather = response.json()

    label["text"] = format_response(weather)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#80c1ff", bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=("Courier", 18))
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Get Weather", font=("Courier", 12), command=lambda: get_weather(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relwidth=0.3, relheight=1)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#80c1ff", bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor="n")

label = tk.Label(lower_frame, font=("Courier", 18), anchor="nw", justify="left", bd=4)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the environment:-

```
Python 3.9.4 
PyCharm 2021.1
macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
```

Here is how I used pyinstaller in terminal:-

```
cd /Users/abcd/PycharmProjects/WeatherApp
pyinstaller --onefile Weather.py
```

Here is what I have done to try to fix the problem:-

1. Removed font=("Courier")
2. Removed bg="#80c1ff"
3. Created another very simple .py (just let user input name and output "Hello" + name) to be converted to exe. This simple .py is not tkinter. The converted exe runs normally.
4. Adjusted pyinstaller --onefile Weather.py to pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole Weather.py

Comment: Sounds like a pyinstaller issue if it works unconverted — so you should focus on that. Regardless, I suggest you replace that bare `except:` with `except Exception as exc:` and the put an indented `print(exc)` beneath it. That way you'll be informed of any error that's occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Add --windowed when you run the command line ie

`--onefile --windowed Weather.py`

Comment: It works fine for me! I've tried `--hidden-import tkinter` which doesn't work.